# fopen and lsattr fail for permission problems

Tags: c, linux, permissions, fopen

I have written many C programs which use `fopen` to work with files on Linux. However, this particular issue has me stumped.

As usual, I have

```c
FILE *filePtr = fopen(strFileName, "r");
if (!filePtr)
{
    printf("Unable to open %s - %s\n", strFileName, strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}
```

which prints shows that the failure happened due to `Unable to open /var/foo/bar - Permission denied`, even when the above code runs as root, and

```sh
[root@MyDevice:/]# whoami
root
[root@MyDevice:/]# ls -al /var/foo/bar 
-rw------- 1 root root 1462272 Aug 26 00:00 /var/foo/bar
[root@MyDevice:/]# lsattr /var/foo/bar 
lsattr: Permission denied While reading flags on /var/foo/bar
[root@MyDevice:/]# df -h | grep root
/dev/root       3.5G  1.1G  2.2G  33% /
[root@MyDevice:/]# stat /var/foo/bar
  File: /var/foo/bar
  Size: 1462272         Blocks: 2864       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: b302h/45826d    Inode: 20046       Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-08-28 15:42:55.312623778 -0500
Modify: 2020-08-26 00:00:00.188294996 -0500
Change: 2020-08-28 15:42:53.362623778 -0500
 Birth: -
```

I have a file `/var/foo/bar` with `/var` mounted as `/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,i_version,data=ordered)`. What am I missing here? Which permissions is root missing, for both `fopen()` and `lsattr`?

The interesting thing is that if I delete `/var/foo/bar` then everything works fine again for a few runs of my (big) program. However, at some point something bad happens and then I'm back in this condition.

**UPDATE**: After running `stat` on the file, the subsequent `lsattr` no longer gives a permission problem error! What does that mean?!

Comment: Can you add the output of running stat on that file, or does it also give an error?

Comment: Unfortunately, my system is currently not in a "bad" state so I cannot perform this test. As I mentioned in the original post, I can still delete the file with `rm` and then, when I code re-creates the file, everything is good with proper `lsattr`. This is the state that I am currently in. But, some time later, for an unknown reason, that file then gets into a state that makes `lsattr` report permission problem

Comment: @AlexanderWolters - I added stat output when the file is in the "bad" state

Comment: `int filePtr = fopen(strFileName, "r");` Huh?  `fopen()` returns a `FILE *` ***pointer***, not an `int`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I apologize. Of course it should be `FILE*` - I screwed up in simplifying the very complicated code. The actual implementation uses `FILE*`. That is not the cause of the problem here

Comment: @PaulGrinberg So, if you do a stat call on the file before access, it does not happen anymore? More of a workaround than a solution, but it appears this is either a device or a kernel issue, not a fault in the program, so maybe ask on the UNIX SE.